# Unable to click option from Div Class Dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My dropdown list contains more then 300 options. When I am trying to click any option through webdriver, Either I am getting the wrong option selected or getting exception that element is not visible. I am attaching below the HTML and webdriver code. Hope you all will resolve my query soon. Thanks in Advance.

```html
<div class="MenuOuter" armenuelementserial="0" style="z-index: 100007; left: 712px; width: 388px; height: 266px; top: 13px; visibility: inherit;">
<div class="MenuScrollUp" style="background-image: url("../../../../resources/images/menu_up.gif"); width: 386px; visibility: inherit; height: 20px;"></div>
<div class="MenuTableContainer" style="top: 20px;">
<table class="MenuTable" style="width: 386px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="MenuTableBody">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap=""> i i </td>
<td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue=" i i "></td>
</tr>
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">102765-ASSET1EC</td>
<td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="102765-ASSET1EC"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">4G_SC01_CUS</td>
<td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="4G_SC01_CUS"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="MenuScrollDown" style="background-image: url("../../../../resources/images/menu_down.gif"); width: 386px; visibility: inherit; height: 20px; top: 244px;"></div>
</div>​
```

1. ```js
   String NewInteraction1 = "//div[@ardbn='Customer']//a";
   WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);// 1 minute 
   wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(NewInteraction1)));
   WebElement link1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(NewInteraction1));
   link1.click();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='MenuTable']//tr"));
   System.out.println(allElements.size());
          for(WebElement element:allElements){
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        if(element.getText().equals("ELEMENT TO BE CLICKED"))
     {
     element.click();
     Thread.sleep(4000);
     break;
     }
        
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before clicking the element scroll the element into view. Try the below code.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",element);
element.click()
```

Also you can avoid looping through all elements by using generic xpath as below,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='MenuTable']/descendant::td[contains(text(),'ELEMENT TO BE CLICKED')]")); //this will find the tablecolumn with text ELEMENT TO BE CLICKED.
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //table[@class='MenuTable']/tr/td[contains(text(),'NOKIA2822')]

Comment: I am getting this exception

Comment: When my dropdown is clicked, it shows fifth option as highlighted. Your code is working but it is selecting the option which is 5 option below the correct option. I am still not able to click the correct option which I want.

Comment: My issue is not resolving and I am not able to select the correct element (isSelected Method Fails).

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='MenuTable']/descendant::td[contains(text(),'NOKIA2822')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",element);//Option selected is 5 option below the NOKIA2822
Thread.sleep(1000);
element.sendKeys();//Noting is happing. Even element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP) is not working.
element.click();//Wrong option is selected

Comment: The same code is working in IE. Can anyone tell me what is the issue with Mozilla.